# Google Analytics Site Totals

Tags: google-analytics, report

is it possible to create a custom report which gives me the totals only for a report based on Site Content - All pages.

My current report is exported to me in csv and includes View, Unique Page Views, Unique visitors etc.  But it returns thousands of rows and i'm only after the totals for these site values.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set time dimension (i.e. ga:month) and required metrics (PV, uPV...). It will give you site totals in selected period segmented by time dimension.